# Disallowing repeated characters and space after punctuation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to "sanitize" a textarea input by disallowing repeated characters like "!!!", "???", etc. add spaces after commas, and I would like to optimize the code because I'm not a pro at this.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XbZrS/6/)

```
$("#post_input").keypress(function() {
        var obj = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            var text = obj.value;
            var selStart = obj.selectionStart;
            var newText = text.replace(/,{2,}|\.{4,}|\!{4,}|\¡{4,}|\?{4,}|\¿{4,}/, function(match, index) {
                if (index < selStart) {
                    selStart -= (match.length - 4);  // correct the selection location
                }
                return(match.substr(0,1));
            });
            if (newText != text) {
                obj.value = newText;
                obj.selectionStart = obj.selectionEnd = selStart;
            }
        }, 1);
    });

    $("#post_input").blur(function(){
      this.value = this.value.replace( /,\s*/g, ', ' );
    });​
```

I would like to merge all in only one regex and function.

Basically, I want to:

- Prevent repeated characters (all kind of characters) to 3. No "aaaaa" or "!!!!!"
- Add space after commas (,) or any kind of punctuation (!) (?) (.)

Comment: Why do you want to turn it all into one big ugly regex?

Comment: @DavidB is there any better solution? I just want to make a clean code.

Comment: No one will ever complain about the number of carriage returns in your code. Morphing validation into one gigantic, ugly regex will just make it harder to maintain.

Comment: In "prevent repetead characters to 3", define "prevent" and "repetead characters to".

Comment: Thanks David, I see your point. @Qtax I don't want to allow repetead any characters to avoid things like "helloooooo" or "WTF!!!!!!!!". Just limit the repetition to 3 max...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Prevent repetead characters (all kind of characters) to 3.

If you mean replace 4 or more repeated characters with single character:

```
str.replace(/(.)\1{3,}/g, '$1');
```

---

> Add space after commas (,) or any kind of punctuation (!) (?) (.)

```
str.replace(/[,.!?:;](?=\S)/g, '$& ');
```

Comment: Great! With the second regex the problem is that it adds spaces if there are 3 of the same punctuation, like "..." it converts it to ". . ."

Comment: @Santiago, add a `+`, like `[,.!?:;]+(?=\S)`.

Comment: The 1st regex would work for **same consecutive characters** (eg. @@, .. etc), but what about **different consecutive characters from a set** (eg. @.) ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa consecutive characters from a set could be matched with `/[@.]{2,}/`. If you want replace it with the first matching character use `/([@.])[@.]+/g` in the first statement.